# Встроить маску vue-phone-mask-input на vue3

Tags: vue3, inputmask

Для ввода номера телефона использовала маску vue-phone-mask-input на vue2. Но сейчас пишу проект на vue3 и там данная маска не работает? Можете подсказать как можно встроить или есть другие аналогичные маски?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент уже 3 года не поддерживается возможно есть другие варианты,
но на гитхабе представлены 2 версии:

### ⚠️ This plugin is unmaintained ⚠️

#### Version for Vue 2 on [maz-ui v2.x](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui)

The version for **Vue 2** is available here: **[maz-ui v2.x - MazPhoneNumberInput](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui/documentation/maz-phone-number-input)**

#### New version for Vue 3 on [maz-ui v3.x](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui-3)

The version for **Vue 3** is available here: **[maz-ui v3.x - MazPhoneNumberInput](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui-3/components/maz-phone-number-input.html)**

---